# Script to create symbolic link

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to make a script that automatically create a symbolic link of a file to my Desktop.

I have made an alias to my script and made the script executable (it works if I just "echo $path"). The expected use would be

```
myalias myfile/
```

Creating a symbolic link through the command

```
ln -sf /absolute/path/to/file ~/Desktop/myfile
```

Here is what I tried (among a few variation):

```
#!/bin/bash
path= realpath $1
link= "~/Desktop/${1::-1}"
ln -sf $path $link
```

and got the following error

```
/usr/bin/myscript: line 3: ~/Desktop/myfile: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome. Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your scripts, you have syntax errors.

Comment: Should the first line be `path="$(realpath "$1")"` perhaps?

Comment: The second line looks wrong too, but it wasn't clear to me what it's supposed to be. Maybe `link="$HOME/Desktop/$(basename "$path")"`? And the third line would be safer as `ln -sf "$path" "$link"`.

Comment: Thank you very much @schrodigerscatcuriosity, I didn't know about shellcheck.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous, it is now working. Although I don't understand why `"$(realpath "$1")"` is better than `realpath $1` ?

Comment: `path= realpath $1` is not proper syntax for setting a bash variable at all. With the space there, it sets $path to an empty variable and then runs `realpath` on $1 without assigning the output to any variable. If you got rid of the space, it would set the `path` variable to the exact value "realpath". and then try to run a program whose name is the value of $1. This is clearly not what you want. You need to use process substitution to set the value to the output of realpath. I can only suggest reading a bash tutorial to learn the basics.